# AWS Inspector connection with EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam, amazon-inspector

How does Amazon Inspector manage to connect with awsagent(Inspector Agent) without any IAM Role?

**This is the setup I have:**

- EC2 with Inspector agent installed via userdata
- The EC2 with No Role
- AWS Inspector with auto-created service linked role  AWSManagedPolicy: **AmazonInspectorServiceRolePolicy**

I have read the **AmazonInspectorServiceRolePolicy** and it only has Read/List rights to EC2. I can see Inspector can still connect and run Hot Assessments. What is giving inspector rights to ssh/run commands into EC2?

Comment: It sounds like the agent on the EC2 instance is running the assessments. That does not require IAM permissions since the agent is already installed on the instance.

Comment: the assessment report and findings gets displayed on inspector service. The agent does communicate with the service.

Comment: Ah, interesting! According to [Getting started with Amazon Inspector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/inspector/latest/userguide/inspector_getting-started.html#inspector_basic-assessment), _"The service installs an Amazon Inspector agent only on those EC2 instances that allow AWS Systems Manager Run Command."_. So, it possibly uses Systems Manager to "pass back" results, but I could not find a specific reference that. I know that the Systems Manager Session Manager works by having the SSM Agent "call back" to the SSM service, so this might be doing something similar.

Comment: I thought the IAM Role is only for pushing the agent. I will try to remove the IAM Role and see.  It sounds a bit shady to me. All IAM Roles are for a principles to be assumed e.g. EC2, Lambda. They shouldn't be using the IAM Role not written for them.

Comment: I've tested Ec2 with no role also and inspector manages to connect, run and report back the result. I am editing the question, removing the role from EC2